# Xamarin Cross platform AES Encryption

Tags: encryption, xamarin, aes

Is there any library available that can be used in the `PCL` that target iOS, Android, and Windows Phone 8 application using `Xamarin`, for implementing `AES 256` encryption.

Comment: Recommendation requests for libraries are off-topic on StackOverflow. You should post this on [softwarerecs.se]. When you do, make that request count: [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Let's create 500 sites that no one uses or knows about cause we can.  How about we go back to how SO was originally used and quick all the whining.

Comment: Android keystore based encryption https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2021/07/android-keystore-based-encryption-and.html

Answer (score 8):

In .NET Standard 1.3 you can now do aes encryption/decryption and hashing https://xamarinhelp.com/cryptography-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4088a7/using-cryptography-in-portable-xamarin-formswindows-phone/).

The author has the same problem and came up with these alternatives:

- [PCL Contrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/)
- [Bouncy Castle PCL](https://github.com/kylewlacy/bouncycastle-pcl)
- [PCL Crypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto)

He also gives another workaround;

> The other work-around is to use some dependency injection with
>   platform-specific code in each platform library and using it in common
>   projects. Xamarin forms provide a minimum depedency feature using
>   DependencyService. The only issue here is writing platform-specific
>   code and it is time consuming.

For more information on the DependencyService check out the [Xamarin documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use dependency injection for the implementation, I tried before 'PCL Crypto', but when i run the application targeting Android device, it throws error at following line, saying that class is not available in target platform (not exact but similar message) 'WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(lengthInBytes)',

Comment: I know this is old, but it's a top Google hit. Has anybody a good Bouncy Castle PCL introduction? Documentation seems to be locked away like the holy grail

Comment: The library should be pretty straight-forward, there is some sparse examples like [here](http://www.thomas-weller.de/en/a-secure-password-hashing-implementation-for-pcls/) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4088a7/using-cryptography-in-portable-xamarin-formswindows-phone/) hope that gets you started.